# How was question 79065 deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Just as a matter of curiosity, how was question #79065, [Identifying the implied gender of nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79065), deleted?

So far as I recall, all other deleted questions I've looked at have a “deleted by” indication;  this one merely says “deleted yesterday”.

Answer (score 6):

It's been deleted fully automatically [by a script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/135907).

> **If the question is more than `30` days old, and ...**
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.
>
> [...]
>
> This check is run every week across all sites.

Comment: In this case, the reason the question has no answers is because it was closed as a duplicate. I thought the general practice is to leave duplicate questions as signposts? Is a -1 score really enough to override that? (IME people who don't have the rep to vote to close a question will often downvote it instead; a -1 score on a closed question isn't really an indication of bad quality.)